# Location of program installation in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I downloaded the `wget` program from `http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/wget/`, and installed it using `./configure; make; sudo make install`. It installed the program at `/usr/local/bin/wget`. What determines where it installs the program at, and can the location of installation be changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wget is already provided by Ubuntu. You don't need to install it externally.

To answer your question, if you read the installation instructions, you will see that you can call the configure script like this:

```
./configure --help
```

The installation prefix is determined by the `--prefix` option. The default is:

```
--prefix /usr/local
```

If you would want to install it into /usr instead, you would do:

```
./configure --prefix /usr
```

Which is not recommended, since only packages provided by Ubuntu should go there. /usr/local is for stuff you install outside of the package manager. If you install wget from the Ubuntu repository for example, it will be installed in /usr.

Comment: So why does it go into `/usr/local/bin`, instead of `/usr/local`?

Comment: @MikaH. `/usr/local` is the prefix. That means binaries get installed into `/usr/local/bin`, documentation into `/usr/local/share/doc`, etc. You can read about the various directories here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard